# How can I track down an error in the CSC in VS 2017?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2017, migration

I am trying to migrate some legacy applications that were inherited and I have run into a problem I am not sure how to solve.

[image: Error Line from Visual Studio]

Clicking the linked text seems to do nothing.  I get that CSC means there is a problem with the configuration, but how can I track down where the /main is being declared that it has an issue with?

Comment: `csc` is the compiler. Did you have any luck googling for `CS2017 cannot specify main if building a module or library`?

Answer (score 0):

Just Install Below

Install-package Microsoft.Net.Compilers -version 2.2.0

Comment: Why? Please explain!

Comment: the csc erro is gone but it shows a missing assembly build error for all the namespaces, even for a project from scratch